# fingerprint verification

Tags: authentication, verification, fingerprint, biometrics

i am doing my final year proj in fingerprint authentication. i 've completed binarization, thinning, minutiae extraction. i am doing it in matlab. i am stuck with the verification. i don't know how to perform verification. so please help me out to solve this problem. i would be grateful to ppl who help .. thanks in advance. please help me out with code for verification or with algorithm atleast... thanks a lot...

Answer (score 2):

The usual way is to use some form of statistical classifier. The most simple is Bayesian (which I believe won't do for fingerprints). In biometry most popular ones are GMM (Gaussian Mixture Model) or HMM (Hidden Markov Model). Another approach is to use neural network as a classifier.

Answer (score 0):

I can't help you with writing your own verification, but i did fingerprint verfication in the past with [Griaule Fingerprint SDK](http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/fingerprint_sdk). I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Take a look at the tutorials shipped with Griaule Fingerprint SDK:

http://www.griaulebiometrics.com/page/en-us/tutorials/csharp-sqlserver-authentication-using-fingerprintsdk/the-code-itself